# var_dumper dump destination

Tags: symfony

Using [VarDumper](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html) Component for Symfony 3.  It works great apart from the fact that the dump is shown in the toolbar instead of the page itself.  I've read the docs but can't find the proper option for dump_destination to show it on the page.

Answer (score 1):

As explained [in the doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html#debugbundle-and-twig-integration),

> Since generating (even debug) output in the controller or in the model
>   of your application may just break it by e.g. sending HTTP headers or
>   corrupting your view, the bundle configures the dump() function so
>   that variables are dumped in the web debug toolbar.
>
> But if the toolbar can not be displayed because you e.g. called
>   die/exit or a fatal error occurred, then dumps are written on the
>   regular output.

So you can call `die()` or `exit()` before returning the response if you want to get your dump on the page.

If you want to dump a specific variable in your page while returning a response, you can pass it to Twig and then use `{{ dump(foo.bar) }}` to dump it in your page.

There is also an explaination on [how to dump into a strin in the doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper/advanced.html#dumpers).

You can also try to dump to `php://output` by [configuring `dump_destination`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/debug.html#dump-destination).